# Fetch retrieve data from database to be array instead of object laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to  convert  retrieving data from object to array but i have this error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

[here is screenshot of whole backtrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q79DF.png)

This is code:

```
 $gallery = DB::table('galleryimages')
            ->join('gallery', 'gallery.id', '=', 'galleryimages.title_id')
            ->select('galleryimages.title_id')->take(10)
            ->get();

        $array= (array) $gallery;

    for( $i=0 ; $i<count($gallery); $i++){
            $galleryimages = DB::table('galleryimages')->join('gallery', 'gallery.id','=','galleryimages.title_id')->where('gallery.id', '=', $array[$i])
                ->select('galleryimages.*','gallery.title','gallery.description')->get();
        }
```

Comment: Try Lists ..   https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: try $gallery->toArray()

Comment: Better post text as text, not screenshots